# Selecting a value from drop down with span id in Selenium PYTHON

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying this for a while and searched different forums but I couldn't find any snippet to do this.

I have a report in which options need to be selected through dropdown using Selenium in python. Below is the HTML structure

```html
<div align="center"> Select Fruit</div>
<p align="center"><br>
 <span id="0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3" style="color: black; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; width: 113px; display: inline-block;" class="sf-element sf-element-control sfc-property sfc-dropdown">
  <div class="sf-element sf-element-dropdown" title="" style="position: relative; width: 100px;">
  <div class="sf-element sf-element-icon" style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 91px; height: 17px; width: 17px;">
   <svg width="17px" height="17px"><path d="M4,6 l7,0 l-3.5,3.5 z" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(1.1333333333333333,1.1333333333333333)" class="Down"></path></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="sf-element sf-element-text-box" style="display: inline-block; word-wrap: break-word; width: 83px;">(None)</div>
   <select class="sf-dropdown-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">(None)</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Grapes</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </span><br></p>
```

I have tried different ways using css selector and XPath but nothing seems to work. Below is the code I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3"]/div/select/option[@value = "Mango"]')
```

Also different variants like options[2] and using css selector but it always give NoSuchElementException.

Can someone please share some insights on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dropdown` is clearly within **`<Select>`** tag. Hence it would be convinient to use the **`Select`** Class as follows:

```
//import
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
//code block
selectOption = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("sf-dropdown-select"))
selectOption.select_by_visible_text("Mango")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add text()="Mongo" instead of @value="Mongo"

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3"]/div/select/option[text() = "Mango"]').click()
```

Comment: Its giving me new error :

InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id="0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3"]/div/select/option[text ="257"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[@id="0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3"]/div/select/option[text ="257"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: could you please double check the xpath of element? is that same ?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with SELECT elements, there is a helper class, [`Select`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms), that makes it a lot easier.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#0e6b87875e914a5f8d72bbee6844bea3 select"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Mango")
```